# python lambda printing space

Tags: python, lambda

In python I want a lambda which return space characters equal to the input.
for example.

```
x=lambda x: return space x times
print "my message",x(10),"my message 2"
```

Output:

> my message<10 space>my message 2

This will cater my need in a particular situation.
I can write a function for this but if this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
x = lambda times:' '*times
print "my message{0}my message 2".format(x(10))         
my message          my message 2
```

Comment: It might be worth calling the variable something different to the name of the function...

Comment: And surely it's easier and more transparent to insert `' ' * 10` directly than make a lambda in this case. (But okay, that is what the OP asked for.)

Comment: @Stuart right, I wanted to add that, but I realized OP said he needs it for some other situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot mux....this means I don't need a function just ' '* times in print..

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @mux is correct, but I think the simpler, more pythonic way to achieve exactly the same thing doesn't require a lambda:

```
def spacetimes(x): return x * ' '
```

then:

```
print "my message",spacetimes(10),"my message 2"
```

You usually need a lambda when you want to pass a function around. For example, I'll revise your code by wrapping it in a function called `msg`:

```
def msg(spacefunc):
    print "my message",spacefunc(10),"my message 2"
```

Then you can call it using a lambda:

```
msg(lambda x: x * ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate to be that guy, but if it doesnt have to be lambda...if all you actually want is the spaces then why not

```
print "my message", ' '*6 ,"my message 2"
```

where '6' can be changed by you.